# Receiving StringIndexOutOfBoundsException during substring / indexOf

Tags: java, string, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, indexof

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("YUGECORPUS.txt")));
        content = content.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ");  
        String search = "George Bush is";
        System.out.print(content.substring(content.indexOf(search), content.substring(content.indexOf(search)).indexOf(".")));
    }

}
```

The error I receive when compiling the code is the following:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -3073945
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at Untitled.main(main.java:14)`.

How do I fix this error, and why is it occuring? The purpose of the following code in the snippet above:

`content.substring(content.indexOf(search), content.substring(content.indexOf(search)).indexOf("."))`

Is print the text from the String `content` from the beginning of the first occurrence of `search` to the first occurrence of a period `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error where you are trying to find the index of `.`:

```
content.substring(content.indexOf(search)).indexOf(".")
```

will give you the index inside the substring, not the index inside `content`. To fix you should add the start index of `search` to it.

For example, if `content` is: `123George Bush is45.` then we would have:

```
content.indexOf(search) -> 3
content.substring(content.indexOf(search)) -> "George Bush is45."
```

and therefore:

```
content.substring(content.indexOf(search)).indexOf(".") -> 16
```

which is incorrect, the correct index is 16 + 3 = 19:

```
content.substring(3, 16) -> "George Bush i"  // wrong
content.substring(3, 19) -> "George Bush is45"  // correct
```

Also if `content` does not contains your `search` string and consecutively a `.` your code might also not work correctly and generate exceptions.

To make the code more error proof you could add checks if `content` contains what you expect, like so (note the fix at `endIndex += startIndex`):

```
int startIndex = content.indexOf(search);
if(startIndex > -1) {
    int endIndex = content.substring(startIndex).indexOf(".");
    if(endIndex > -1) {
        endIndex += startIndex;
        String foundString = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        System.out.print(foundString);
    }
}
```

Explicitly making the checks instead of putting everything in a one line also will make the code much easier to debug and find errors.

**Edit:** as pointed out by @Andreas, the instructions

```
int endIndex = content.substring(startIndex).indexOf(".");
endIndex += startIndex;
```

can be simplified with

```
int endIndex = content.indexOf('.', startIndex);
```

This is the updated code:

```
int startIndex = content.indexOf(search);
if(startIndex > -1) {
    int endIndex = content.indexOf('.', startIndex);
    if(endIndex > -1) {
        String foundString = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        System.out.print(foundString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I don't quite understand how I could add the start index of search to it to fix it, as you noted is necessary. Isn't that what I'm doing with `content.indexOf(search))`? If not, how do I correct this?

Comment: I added an example in the answer to help understand better. To fix you can do like I did in my code, you save `content.indexOf(search))` in a variable like my `startIndex` and add it to your `.` index (`endIndex` in my case)

Comment: `content.substring(startIndex).indexOf(".") + startIndex` is the long and **slow** way to write `content.indexOf('.', startIndex)`.

Comment: @Andreas good catch, wasn't aware of that, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's taking your substring and finding it, then reading through the file again and finding the **first** period. So, when

This. Something. George Bush is blah blah blah.

It gets your first argument as a larger number than the second one, because it's finding the first period after "This".

If you want to keep doing it that way, you'll have to truncate the string after finding "George bush is" to put it at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

#### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

To help us help you, you should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is easily done by replacing the first line in your method, e.g.

```
String content = "In a galaxy far, far away, George Bush is happy. That is good.";
```

That way, we can actually reproduce your problem.

#### Problem

So, having done that, let's split out your code to see what is going wrong:

```
String content = "In a galaxy far, far away, George Bush is happy. That is good.";
content = content.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ");  
String search = "George Bush is";

int searchIdx = content.indexOf(search);
String substring = content.substring(searchIdx);
int periodIdx = substring.indexOf(".");
System.out.println("searchIdx = " + searchIdx);
System.out.println("substring = " + substring);
System.out.println("periodIdx = " + periodIdx);
System.out.print("content.substring(" + searchIdx + ", " + periodIdx + ") = ");
System.out.flush();
System.out.println(content.substring(searchIdx, periodIdx));
```

*Output*

```
searchIdx = 27
substring = George Bush is happy. That is good.
periodIdx = 20
content.substring(27, 20) = Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -7
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

Here you can see that the problem is that `periodIdx` is 20, i.e. less than the `searchIdx` value of 27, causing the `substring(27, 20)` to fail.

That is because `periodIdx` is an index into `substring`, not an index into `content`.

#### Solution 1 (not ideal)

One way to fix that, is to simply add `searchIdx` to `periodIdx`, e.g.

```
int periodIdx = substring.indexOf(".") + searchIdx;
```

*Output*

```
searchIdx = 27
substring = George Bush is happy. That is good.
periodIdx = 47
content.substring(27, 47) = George Bush is happy
```

#### Solution 2 (not ideal)

Another way to fix it, is to substring the `substring` variable instead, since that is what the index is for:

```
int periodIdx = substring.indexOf(".");
System.out.print("substring.substring(0, " + periodIdx + ") = ");
System.out.println(substring.substring(0, periodIdx));
```

*Output*

```
substring.substring(0, 20) = George Bush is happy
```

#### Solution 3 (ideal)

Both of the previous solutions will get you the desired result. They are however not *ideal* solutions, because `content.substring(searchIdx)` takes a *copy* when it creates the substring.

A better solution is to perform the second index lookup *starting* at the point returned by the first lookup:

```
int searchIdx = content.indexOf(search);
int periodIdx = content.indexOf('.', searchIdx);
System.out.print("content.substring(" + searchIdx + ", " + periodIdx + ") = ");
System.out.println(content.substring(searchIdx, periodIdx));
```

*Output*

```
content.substring(27, 47) = George Bush is happy
```

Also notice that the search value to `indexOf()` was changed from `"."` to `'.'`, since it is faster to search for a single character than it is to search for a string, even a single-character string.

That is much better code.

#### Conclusion

Your `main()` method should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("YUGECORPUS.txt")));
    content = content.replace("\n", " ").replace("\r", " ");  
    String search = "George Bush is";
    int searchIdx = content.indexOf(search);
    System.out.print(content.substring(searchIdx, content.indexOf('.', searchIdx)));
}
```

Notice that the `searchIdx` is done separately, so it only has to be done once, unlike your code that had to search past *more than 3 million(!)* characters **twice**.

It also makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful. However, I already accepted an answer- when I'll get to the requisite number of reputation points, I will upvote your response. :)

Comment: I have a quick question, though: how would I revise the code so that it would print out the substring until the next comma `,`, if there exists one before the next period `.`?